# Deploying Azure ARM Templates using Parameter Functions not pulling through correct values

Tags: azure, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019, azure-rm-template

I've been trying to set the value of a parameter, based on the value I set of another parameter. This wasn't working but then I discovered the Parameters with Functions JSON example on the [Azure GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-json-samples/blob/master/azure-resource-manager/parameterswithfunctions.json)

This is giving the same behaviour as my own template so is perfect to show the issues I am having.

As you can see from the JSON linked to above, the parameter `hostingPlanName` should concat the parameter `siteName` with the string `-plan`. When I edit the parameter file, I see the function instead of the value it resolves to.

[image: Azure Function Parameter Example]

This example pulls other values in to set the value of `siteName`, I wondered if that was the reasons so hard set `siteName` to 'TEST' and the result for `hostingPlanName` was the same.

I haven't deployed this example, but if I deploy my real template, it throws an error with Bad Request for the name of the resource I am deploying.

Is this me or is this not possible anymore?

I am using VS2019 Community.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great place to use [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-syntax#variables). Your `hostingPlanName` is not set directly by user input (as parameters should be), but is a dynamic evaluation of a complex value based on a parameter, so it should be a variable.